# Como limitar el acceso a archivos de media con django

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework

Estoy contruyendo una API rest creada en Django que es consumida por una pagina creada con react, mi problema es que cuando quiero eliminar un archivo que esta en uso por la pagina me salta la excepción [WinError32]

mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
class VideoAPI(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def put(self, request):
        try:
            """
            Tambien me gustaria saber si existe una forma practica de serializar
            request.data para no tener que hacer las conversiones por mi cuenta
            """
            data       = request.data
            user       = request.user
            video_date = data['video_date']
            video_type = data['video_type']
            
            if data['video_file'] == 'null':
                video_file = None
            else:
                video_file = data['video_file']
           
            video_object = Video.Objects.get(pk=data['pk'])

            if not video_file is None:
                try:
                    """Tambien intente con os.remove('ruta del video')"""
                    video_object.video_file.close()
                    video_object.video_file.delete()
                    video_object.video_file = video_file

                except OSError as e:
                    """El error retornado es [WinError32]"""
                    print(e)
                    return Response(status=400)

            video_object.video_date = video_date
            video_object.video_file = video_file
            video_object.video_type = video_type

            video_object.save()

            return Response(status=200)
        except:
            return Response(status=400)
```

por lo cual quiero saber si existe alguna forma de denegar el acceso a un archivo en especifico mientras edito el objeto, cerrar el archivo para todos los clientes o alguna otra solución practica al problema.

Comment: Has comprobado cuál es el proceso que tiene abierto el archivo en ese momento? No tiene demasiado sentido que el archivo esté abierto por python. O estás abriéndolo desde otra aplicación en paralelo?

Comment: EL archivo de video es consumido desde la pagina web y puede ser reproducido en cualquier momento por uno o más usuarios por lo cual desde el panel de administración que estoy creando necesito poder editar el objeto que contiene el video ya sea para cambiar el video (que puede estar en uso o no) o modificar algun campo. @CésarGonzález

Comment: Te diría que sólo se me ocurren dos opciones (y cada cual me da más grima): tener en el front un observable que detecte cuándo se va a borrar un vídeo y cambiar el src del vídeo por un string vacío justo antes de borrarlo o servir los vídeos desde tu view haciendo una copia al vuelo del vídeo original asociado al modelo. Como te digo, ninguna me gusta en absoluto.

Quizá otra opción sería no borrarlo en el momento y crear luego un comando dedicado a la limpieza de los archivos que se queden huérfanos :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que estuve investigando estos dias no encontre una solucion practica para este problema, os.remove(path) no permite eliminar archivos en uso para windows pero en sistemas con Unix los elimina sin problemas.

pd: Hice las pruebas tanto en un macOs como en ubuntu server.